# How to render an html template from express, while on Angular5

Tags: angular, http, express, templates, render

So, I ran into a fairly unique situation. I was tasked to convert an existing repository that's running server-side express and html as its view engine, to express with client-side Angular (5).

I got stuck, when I arrived at an html view that I couldn't convert to Angular, and would like to have express render this view as-is from the server side instead.

Right now, I have a form component, that returns a Promise of an http post request through a service I had written in Angular, and that post request (from express), is supposed to finish with a render of an html view from an express response object. But when express runs into that render call, nothing happens and I'm still on the same form component.

I know this is likely bad practice to attempt doing this, but is it possible to have express render a view to the client (while interpolating data passed from the request body)?

Comment: have you seen the http request, do you get html content in the form of a string, if yes then I think you can try replacing the template url to the newly received html string and then it should work. If possible please show me the network request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is bad practice. Very bad practice. Angular was made to not use server-side rendering, to make Single Page Applications.

You should not do that.

But since you asked, yes, it is possible.

Without code, I'll have to make it general, but I guess you already have a node application using express.

What you could is create your page and serve it like so

```
app.get('myCustomPage', (req, res) => {
  /* serve your page */
});
```

And in other cases, you could tell express to serve the angular application

```
app.configure(() => {
  app.use((req, res) => { /* serve Angular here */});
});
```

(Note : this should be your last `use` statement if it redirects in any case).

Last solution is to use the Hash Location Strategy with Angular with

```
RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

Meaning your application will handle its own routing, meaning that you can serve your custom page on another URL with ease.

But again, **do not do that**.